# Enter values, generate a list, and search

Tags: c++, homework, binary-search

My assignment in school:

- **Read in names to sort** until the user types the “enter” key
- After sorting and displaying the array of strings
- **Do a binary search** to find if the string is in the array
- If the string is in the array, **tell the user the index of the string.**
- If the string is not in the array, tell the user that it is missing.

Can this get smaller, faster, and easier to read?

```
#include < iostream >
#include < string > 
#include < algorithm >
#include < vector > 

using namespace std;

void main ( ) {              vector < int >   nameTemp          { };
                    vector < vector < int > > nameContainer     { };
                                      bool    Continue        ( true );
                                      char    c                 { };
do  
{       /*       Stay in loop while ( !Continue )       */
    do
    {   Continue = true;
        cout << "\n\tNew Entry: ";
        while ( ( c = cin.get ( ) ) != '\n' )
        {
            nameTemp.push_back ( c );
            Continue = false;
        }

        if ( !Continue )/*    ( if not empty )      */
            nameContainer.push_back ( nameTemp );

        /*  Throw away temp     */
        nameTemp.erase ( nameTemp.begin ( ), nameTemp.end ( ) );

        /*  Comparison Lambda   */
        /*  Descending order; substitute return (<) with (>)    */
        sort (  nameContainer.begin ( ), 
                nameContainer.end ( ), 
                [ ] ( const vector < int > & a, const vector < int > & b )
                    { return a < b; } ); 

        system ( "cls" );

        /* Range based for loops printing 2D vector     */
        size_t RowNumber { 1 };

        for ( const auto & Column : nameContainer )
        {                   /*  Extra space extra digit     */ 
            if ( RowNumber < 10 )   { cout << "    "; }
            if ( RowNumber > 9 )    { cout << "   "; }

            cout << RowNumber << " | ";

            for ( size_t Row : Column )
                cout << static_cast < char > ( Row );

            cout << "\n";
            RowNumber++;
        }
    }   
    while ( !Continue );

    Continue = false;
    /*  Stay in loop while ( !Continue )    */
    do
    {   Continue = true;
        cout << "\n\tSearch Entries: ";
        while ( ( c = cin.get ( ) ) != '\n' )
        {
            nameTemp.push_back ( c );
            Continue = false;
        }                       /*  Strings make for easy printing  */
        string sNameTemp    { nameTemp.begin ( ), nameTemp.end ( ) };

        if ( !Continue )
        {       /*      Active check for No Result  */
                  size_t ColumnNumber        { 0 };
                    bool Result               { };
                    bool noResult           ( true );

            for ( const auto & Column : nameContainer )
            {   /*                      Binary search through 0 index   */ 
                    bool Result     =   binary_search (  Column.begin ( ),
                                                         Column.end ( ),
                                                         nameTemp.at ( 0 )  );
                     int nameSize   =   nameTemp.size ( );
                     int columnSize =   Column.size ( );
/*  Vaidate Size    */
                if ( nameSize != columnSize ) Result = false;
                if ( nameSize == columnSize ) Result = true;
/*  Validate Position   */
                if ( Result )
                {
                    for ( int Row = 0; Row < nameSize; Row++ )
                    {
                        if ( Column [ Row ] != nameTemp [ Row ] )
                            Result = false;
                    }
                }
                ColumnNumber++;
 /* Print Index */
                if ( Result ) 
                {
                    cout << "\t" << sNameTemp << " Found at index ";
                    cout << ColumnNumber << "\n";
                    noResult = false;
                }                   
            }
            if ( noResult )
                cout << "\t Found Nothing \n";
        }
/*  Throw away temp */
        nameTemp.erase ( nameTemp.begin ( ), nameTemp.end ( ) );
        sNameTemp.erase ( sNameTemp.begin ( ), sNameTemp.end ( ) );
    }
    while ( !Continue );
}                       /*  Stay inside main loop   */
while ( Continue );

}
```

Comment: If you wish to provided updated code, make sure your answer has further explanation about the changes.  You can still edit your deleted answer, which I can undelete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use functions

Putting all your code in one function is hard to maintain and read. By dividing your code into functions you can name the functions so that the code becomes self documenting.

### Includes are illegal

Technically this is not legal:

```
#include < iostream >
#include < string > 
#include < algorithm >
#include < vector >
```

The space after `<` and before `>` is part of the name (as defined by the standard). If this is working you are relying on compiler specific behavior.

### Using namespace std

This is bad practice (and a bad habbit).

```
using namespace std;
```

The namespace `std` is deliberately short so that using the prefix is not that inconvenient. Prefer to prefex items in the standard namespace with `std::`.

### Variable Names

```
 {              vector < int >   nameTemp          { };
                vector < vector < int > > nameContainer     { };
                                  bool    Continue        ( true );
                                  char    c                 { };
```

That just looks weird.

```
 vector < int >            nameTemp          { };
 vector < vector < int > > nameContainer     { };
 bool                      Continue          ( true ); // Though careful `continue` is a reserved word.
 char                      c                 { };
```

Looks more normal. But more importantly. You should declare variables as close to the point of use as you can. Don't use the C technique of declaring everything at the top of the function. Declare it just before you use it.

This is long winded way

```
    while ( ( c = cin.get ( ) ) != '\n' )
    {
        nameTemp.push_back ( c );
        Continue = false;
    }
```

of saying

```
    std::getline(std::cin, nameTemp);
```

Sure you can do this.

```
    /*  Throw away temp     */
    nameTemp.erase ( nameTemp.begin ( ), nameTemp.end ( ) );
```

or you can just call clear()

```
    nameTemp.clear();
```

Or you can just declare it at the correct location so that the constructor initializes it correctly before use.

```
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {        
         // Though this also pushes empty line (we can work around that)
         nameContainer.push_back(line);
    }
```

### Sort every iteration not required

You sort after every iteration.

```
    /*  Comparison Lambda   */
    /*  Descending order; substitute return (<) with (>)    */
    sort (  nameContainer.begin ( ), 
            nameContainer.end ( ), 
            [ ] ( const vector < int > & a, const vector < int > & b )
                { return a < b; } );
```

You could just sort once after you have loaded all the words.

This looks it can be done with a tab:

```
        if ( RowNumber < 10 )   { cout << "    "; }
        if ( RowNumber > 9 )    { cout << "   "; }
```

I would just do:

```
        cout << "\t";
```

### You are doing a binary search of a word

You should be doing a binary search of the container.

```
        for ( const auto & Column : nameContainer )
        {   /*                      Binary search through 0 index   */ 
                bool Result     =   binary_search (  Column.begin ( ),
                                                     Column.end ( ),
                                                     nameTemp.at ( 0 )  );
```

## This is what I would do:

```
int main()
{
    // Read a line into a string (stopping at the '\n')
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    // Treat the line we just read as a stream.
    // That allows us to read words from the line very easily.
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);


    std::vector<std::string>   words;
    std::string                word;
    // Read a set of space separated words from the stream 
    while(lineStream >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(lines);
    }

    /* An alternative to the loop above is:
    std::vector<std::string>    words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(lineStream),
                                      std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
    */

    // Sort the array.
    std::sort(std::begin(words), std::end(words)); // default order is fine.

    // Print the array
    std::copy(std::begin(words), std::end(words),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));


    std::string   find;
    while(std::cin >> find)
    {
        auto findPos = std::lower_bound(std::begin(words), std::end(words),find);
        if (findPos == std::end(words)) {
            std::cout << find << " is missing\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << find << " at " << std::distance(std::begin(words), findPos) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very super clever; I make rehash with enter separated strings. I like your way better; do you think there's a way to separate strings with enter and proceed on empty? Or is that weird.

Comment: @bedlam: No really. You could copy all lines into `words` them remove the empty lines with `delete/erase idiom`